# Find distance from contour to a Point opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, point, contour, imaging

I would create a Matrix that has in the coloumn[i] the distances from a fixed Point (mass center(mc(i)) of a contour) to the Points of the contour[i].

This is the code where I find contours and mass centers:

```
findContours(binMat, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));

/// Get the moments
vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    mu[i] = moments(contours[i], false);
}

///  Get the mass centers
vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    mc[i] = Point2d(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
}
```

This code is working well.

Next, I tried many way to find the distance, but having many problems because I'm new programming with C++ and using OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    mc[i] = Point2d(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);

    KeyPoint k;
    k.pt = mc[i];

    float d = (k.pt.x,k.pt.y, centerX,centerY);
}
```

A function to calculate distance between 2 points

```
float distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{

    float d = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));

    return d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim!! Your advice was useful, I solved the problem this way: `vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
 raggio.resize(contours.size());
 for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
 {
  mc[i] = Point2d(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
  KeyPoint center;
  center.pt = mc[i];
  raggio[i].resize(contours[i].size());
  for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); j++)
  {
   KeyPoint k;
   k.pt = contours[i][j];
   float d = distance((int)center.pt.x, (int)center.pt.y, (int)k.pt.x, (int)k.pt.y);
   raggio[i][j] = d;
  }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in openCV for this; [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest).

Comment: Thanks Aidenhjj for the fast reply! I've tried that function and it works, but I need to know all the distances from every point of the contour to the mass center! Instead this function returns only the distance from the nearest point of the contour.

Comment: so just get the x and y properties of every point and subtract the centre x and y and then use good old Pythagoras to find the distance.

Comment: This is the point! I've already done this project on Matlab and there I used the "good old Pythagoras" :) The fact is that I don't know how to get the x and y properties because it's the first time I program in C++/openCV!

Comment: I think if you loop through the contours vector, you should get openCV `Points`. To access the x and y properties just do `pt.x` or `pt.y`. But I've always used the Python API.